# Unable to center login form in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to centre login form in react native for that I have wrapped TextInput and TouchableOpacity in View tag and assigned relevant properties to View tag but it is not placing whole form in center.Moreover the size of form elements also gets shrink.

Below is my code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import { View,Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {

  return(

 <View>
   <Text style={styles.head}>Register here</Text> 

   <Signup/>
 </View>
);

}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 head:{
   color:'blue',
   fontWeight:'bold',
   textAlign:'center',
   marginTop:20,
   fontSize:25
 }
});
```

**Signup.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class Signup extends Component{

state={
    name:'',
    password:''
}

handleName = (name) => {

    this.setState({name:name})      
}

handlePwd = (pwd) => {

    this.setState({password:pwd})
}

alertMsg = (name,pwd) => {

    alert(name + " " + pwd);
}

render(){

    return(

        <View>

            <View style={styles.layout}>  

            <TextInput style={styles.input}
                       placeholder='Name'
                       onChangeText={this.handleName}/>

            <TextInput style={styles.input}
                       placeholder='Password'
                       secureTextEntry={true}
                       onChangeText={this.handlePwd}/>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.buton}
              onPress={() => this.alertMsg(this.state.name,this.state.password)}>
                  <Text style={styles.submit}>SUBMIT</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> 

            </View>
      
        </View>
     );
   }

}

export default Signup;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

layout:{
    flexDirection:'column',
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
},
   input:{
       marginTop:20,
       borderColor:'blue',
       borderRadius:3,
       borderWidth:1,
       paddingLeft:10
   },
   submit:{
       textAlign:'center',
       color:'white',
       padding:15,
       fontWeight:'bold'
   },
   buton:{
       backgroundColor:'blue',
       borderRadius:3,
       marginTop:20
   }
});
```

Here is an output:

[image]

How can I get desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a View to wrap your main container and layout should have a flex:1 to take all the space. For text boxes you can provide a width in percentage like the code below.

Here's code for render and the styles.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.layout}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Name"
          onChangeText={this.handleName}
        />

        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Password"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          onChangeText={this.handlePwd}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buton}
          onPress={() => this.alertMsg(this.state.name, this.state.password)}>
          <Text style={styles.submit}>SUBMIT</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  layout: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  input: {
    marginTop: 20,
    borderColor: 'blue',
    borderRadius: 3,
    borderWidth: 1,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    width: '70%',
  },
  submit: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    padding: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  buton: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderRadius: 3,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});
```

Comment: No its not working properly no effect on layout after adding `flex:1`

Comment: did you try the whole code ? you dont need the wrapper view as well

Comment: Yeah I tried it actually its a child component and  I am calling it in a parent component.

Comment: Please take a look I have updated the code.Now it includes whole code.

Comment: Why not you move the register here inside the login component ? any specific reason

Comment: Here Main component is `App.js`  in this I am importing `Signnup.js`.

Comment: Do you want to move the 'Register here' to the middle as well or just the form ?

Comment: I want only from in the center and register at the top of page.

Comment: tested it, use the style i gave for the signup and put a flex:1 for the view in app.js like  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

Comment: That worked bro but when keyboard opens whole form shifts upward how can I make from stable.

Comment: If you dont move it upward then its hard to type right ? you can use something like a keyboardavoidingview as well

Comment: okk bro but could u please explain how form come in center with above changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216274/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-digvijay).